# How can I prevent water from remaining in a flexible shower hose?

Tags: shower

installing a handheld shower over tub, all new plumbing.  diverter valve on tub spout.  pressure-balancing control and no fixed shower head.

I want to make sure water will not sit in the handheld hose between uses.  It seems that it should siphon out thru the tub spout when the flow is turned off, please confirm?

Comment: Water happily sites in pipes all over the world, and it does neither the water nor the pipe any harm.

Comment: And if there is any part of the hose that has two sides of  a curve  pointing above horizontal, *some* water will remain.

Comment: Since it's a hand-held shower head, simply let it hang into the tub for a few moments as you wipe the excess water off yourself, and before getting out. Depending on the angles involved, you'll likely get an ounce or two sitting in the shower head that won't flow out due to gravity, but that's not created an issue at my house. I do understand the desire to do this - it eliminates that sort burst of cold water when you first turn the diverter.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve or gusard against?

Comment: Trying to guard against the short burst of cold water when you first turn on the diverter.  Secondarily, not quite the same as water in a closed pioe (would be exposed to air).  Thanks everybody for the great comments.

Answer (score 1):

i would have to disagree with daniel above.  standing water leads to mineral deposition and galvanic corrosion much faster, and in places it may not normally happen.  pathogenically, you could also be hosting lots of little bacteria and fungii in that standing water, particularly on a well water connection.  hand wands sometimes go months between uses, so i think you are probably right in trying to avoid this.

in these installations, it depends on a few things:

1)  loops in the wand hose will hold the most water.

2)  some wands have a backflow valve in them,  this will prevent any break in the column and could leave water in a hose no matter what you do.

3)  some tub diverters don't open properly on stop of water.   they pop open when the pressure comes on again, but dont necessarily release when the water flow stops.  that could hold water above them.

4)  some thermostatic mixing valves (like the moen 3285 and 3210) are notorious for not letting water flow back through them freely or predictably.  this is just the valve design and cant be worked around.